# can you remove a hair on the image sensor in light room?

Tags: lightroom, sensor, image-processing, cleaning

i took a series of pictures yesterday and discovered that shooting around f/13, f/16, there is what appears to be a hair located on the image sensor and is visible in the pictures where the lens is stepped down.  it appears as like a blurry translucent strand of spaghetti in the upper left corner of the pictures.

some of the photos the enigma is only present in the sky; other pictures it is present on a building with beautiful stained glass.

is there a tool in lightroom that magically fixes this for me? or can  i somehow go pixel by pixel and fix the problem somehow?

Answer (score 4):

The [spot removal](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/enhanced-spot-removal.html) tool is what you want, you can either click to heal spots or drag for things like hairs.